# Ubuntu: How do I download PPA software over HTTPS?

Tags: tls, ubuntu

The default PPA address is: http://ppa.launchpad.net

How do I connect to this via https, or use a mirror with https?

Yes, I'm aware that the packages are signed. Thing is, signing keys can be stolen.

I'm aware it's easier to break https that to steal a signing key. However this does not make https useless. In today's world multiple layers of security are mandatory, I'm amazed that packages are still served over http by default.

Comment: *"..multiple layers of security are mandatory.."* - are they? And if this is the case, have you made sure that you really can trust the author of the PPA, that you can trust the authors of the software he is packaging that there are no explicit or implicit backdoors (i.e. bugs)? These parts might be more of a problem than missing https for transferring already protected (i.e. signed) data.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich and others: you may be correct in theory but since TLS has become de-facto standard, there is surely a gain in simplicity and therefore security by making it the ironclad rule. One less thing to arbitrate, one less thing to go wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple: Ubuntu provides e.g. http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu/, but not [http**s**://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu/](https://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu/). Nothing you can do about this. How could any mirror be more secure than the origin?

File a bug report to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ if you want to see http**s**://ppa.launchpad.net/, but don't set your hopes too high.

Answer (score 1):

You are making a bold claim that adding HTTPS to the PPA mirrors on top of the code-signing mechanism is a security improvement. Let's take a look at what those two things are doing:

### Code Signing

I'm not familiar with how code signing works in Ubuntu / apt, and I have not been successful at finding it on Google. Are the packages signed by the developers, or by the mirror itself? If anyone has a link, I'd be grateful. I'll assume they are signed by the mirror because that makes more sense.

So, the security model is that you have a `.deb` file that you want to install (the method by which you got it is irrelevant), and you can verify the signature on the package to ensure that it is genuine. Short of an attacker stealing the private key and signing their own version, this seems pretty water-tight.

### HTTPS / TLS

The value this adds is that the server can cryptographically prove that it is who it says it is, and all communications can not be Man-in-the-Middle'd. Let's look at this in detail:

#### Case 1: Neither PPA code signing key or HTTPS server key are compromised

Everything is good. You are getting double protection. HTTPS is not adding any value.

#### Case 2: PPA code signing key not compromised, HTTPS server key compromised

This is equivalent to the current practice of not having HTTPS. So an attacker can MitM your connection to `https://ppa.launchpad.net` and therefore apt will not be able to give you a malicious version of the `.deb` file. BUT you will not be able to install it because the signature won't verify properly. HTTPS is not adding any value.

#### Case 3: PPA code signing key compromised, HTTPS server key not compromised

The attacker will not be able to MitM your connection to `https://ppa.launchpad.net`. HTTPS *is* adding value.

#### Case 4: Both keys compromised

You're in trouble. HTTPS is not adding any value.

---

The only case in which HTTPS adds value is if the PPA signing key is compromised, but the server TLS key is not. How likely is this to happen? Clearly the people in charge of the design of this system do not consider it to be a significant threat. As @kay said in that answer, if you want to put pressure on this issue, then file a bug.

---

As an aside, the design pattern of using HTTP for protocols that have built-in crypto is fairly common and accepted. This is a very similar protocol design to, for example CMP or AIA for managing certificates: there is no need for these protocols to go over TLS because the protocol itself has built-in crypto protection. Moreover, the origin entity that you want to authenticate is the CA (or in this case, the code signer), which particular mirror you got the file from is almost irrelevant. (compare this to the use-case that TLS is designed for, for example, connecting to `www.facebook.com` where the identity of the server is the important part).

Comment: It's not watertight, it has been broken before and will be broken again. See https://www.debian.org/security/2016/dsa-3733. dsa-3733 bypasses ALL of the cases you mentioned above. In addition to dsa-3733, private signing keys CAN AND DO get stolen.

Comment: Also, HTTPS helps with privacy and avoiding identification.  It would be easy to fingerprint a machine based on which updates it downloads.  That can then be used to track and identify that machine.  Using HTTPS makes that kind of tracking a lot harder.

Comment: Broken again with [CVE-2019-3462](https://www.debian.org/security/2019/dsa-4371). The defence in depth principle applies here as much as anywhere else. **The claim that https provides no or minimal security benefit is simply false.**

Comment: Saying that that TLS is not necessary because of signatures is like saying that the front door on your apartment building should be left open because your apartment has its own door inside.